# Display Java Source Code in HTML

Tags: java, html

I have some Java code that I want to display on my web site.  The point of sharing this code is not for for the viewers to use, it is just for them to see.  (Although I am not opposed to them using it.)  It is about 10 packages, each with 10 classes.  What is the best way to make it viewable and navigatable in HTML?  I am fairly new at this.

I am not necessarily trying to make it pretty...I just want it to be functional.  I am also trying to avoid copy and pasting 100 individual files.  I want to paste the entire Java project into a folder, then allow the user to access that folder and view its contents from on the website.  So something like a folder system, where when they navigate to a .java, it displays the contents of that .java below the folder tree.

How can I accomplish this?  I am not really sure where to begin.

Comment: Post a link to the GitHub repository? Or even PasteBin.

Comment: You could put it on Github or Bitbucket and link to it. They have very neat source code browsers. You can editorialize a bit on top of that. There must be widgets to include snippets for example, and of course, you can deep-link directly to individual files. You may want to create a tag to keep the links working forever.

Comment: Can I link to Github while keeping the rest of my public github stuff out of view?  I don't want them looking at my ugly code :-p

Comment: Sure, create a public repository just for the stuff that you want folks to see.

Comment: Is it possible to link them to it in a way that it won't also link them to my other public repos?